# Command failed while buildozer android debug deploy run

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to install buildozer for making apk from kivy but I am continuously getting an error while running the command :

buildozer android debug deploy run

I am getting an error

```
Exception in thread background thread for pid 25195:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.9.egg/sh.py", line 1683, in wrap
fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.9.egg/sh.py", line 2662, in background_thread
handle_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.9.egg/sh.py", line 2349, in fn
return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.9.egg/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127:
```

RAN:

```
/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh
```

STDOUT:

```
/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found
```

STDERR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1276, in <module>
main()
File "/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
ToolchainCL()
File "/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 725, in __init__
getattr(self, command)(args)
File "/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
File "/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
File "/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 580, in build_recipes
recipe.build_arch(arch)
File "/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 28, in build_arch
shprint(sh.Command('./autogen.sh'), _env=env)
File "/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
for line in output:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.9.egg/sh.py", line 953, in next
self.wait()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.9.egg/sh.py", line 879, in wait
self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.9.egg/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127:
```

RAN:

```
/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh
```

STDOUT:

```
/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found


STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/ashmit/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/Ashmit-Laptop:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1480,unix/Ashmit-Laptop:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1480'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = 'gnome-keyring'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/home/ashmit/buildozer'
#     LOGNAME = 'ashmit'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'wayland'
#     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '1674'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.784OF1'
#     HOME = '/home/ashmit'
#     USERNAME = 'ashmit'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_IN'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6402'
#     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/c031c37a_aec3_4556_a510_a92cccf3dbc7'
#     GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY = ':1'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'ashmit'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.125'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/ashmit/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/ashmit/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/ashmit'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/ashmit/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/ashmit/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/ashmit/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

on Ubuntu Linux 21 any help will be appreciated
i am sorry for this might be a silly mistake THANK YOU!